# Backbone relational model saving error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, json, backbone-relational

I get the error, when I try to save the model with .save()

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
```

The funny thing is that modelInstance.toJSON() works just fine.

*The error is thrown at backbone.js line 1148*
which is:

```
params.data = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options));
```

Here is how I've setup of the model:

```
var Clip = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    idAttribute: "mediaItemId",
    defaults: {
        node: {}
    }
});

var clipCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Clip
});

var mainModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    url: '/api/v0/videostate',
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasMany 
            ,key: 'videoCollection'
            ,relatedModel: Clip
            ,collectionType: clipCollection
            ,includeInJSON: Clip.idAttribute
            ,reverseRelation: {
                key: 'parent',
                includeInJSON: Clip.idAttribute
            }
        }
    ],
});

var modelInstance = new mainModel()

modelInstance.fetch();
```

The JSON that's loaded into the model:

[image]

Comment: There must be something in your code that make an object attribute a referrence to itself or one of it's parents. which version of backbone and backbone-relational you are using?

Comment: Backbone 1.0
Backbone-relational.js 0.8.6

Comment: Could you give me return value of `modelInstance.toJSON()` (use pastebin or any other tool like that), and if you are using chrome please see backtrace of error and also tell me last points from backbone-relational.

Comment: So, as I can't see and I don't know what `Clip.idAttribute` returns but I don't think that's the `mainModel.idAttribute` (in your reverse relation), change that in your own code! and tell me!

Comment: Here is the trace:
http://i.imgur.com/fQ2GCxx.png
toJSON: http://i.imgur.com/LWQLQsk.png
If I change the Clip.idAttribute to "mediaItemId" it works, but it only includes the ID string in the encoded JSON, but I want the full object.

Comment: The problem is exactly in that point. No need to hard-code that, just `includeInJSON: Clip.idAttribute` in reverse relation to `includeInJSON: this.idAttribute`. I'll post answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `includeInJSON: Clip.idAttribute` in reverse relation to `includeInJSON: Clip.prototype.idAttribute`

Something like this

```
{
    type: Backbone.HasMany 
    ,key: 'videoCollection'
    ,relatedModel: Clip
    ,collectionType: clipCollection
    ,includeInJSON: Clip.prototype.idAttribute
    ,reverseRelation: {
       key: 'parent',
       includeInJSON: Clip.prototype.idAttribute
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives an immediate error of 
"Cannot read property 'idAttribute' of undefined"

Comment: But it was a stupid idea from me, because Clip is just a function at the time so it can't have a property.

Comment: It works, but the serialized array is now: {"videoCollection":["v1.cdn:91852085.mp4","v1.cdn:94093890.mp4","v1.cdn:94093891.mp4"]...
not the whole video model. Maybe I misunderstand what backbone.realated can do.

Comment: If you think the answer is correct then accept (or upvote) it :). That problem can be solved by setting `includeInJSON: ["string array of attributes you want to include"]` [Relational Docs](http://backbonerelational.org/#relations-includeInJSON)

Comment: Ohhh, damn. And it's there indeed. Thank you! If you modify your answer from "this.idAttribute" to Clip.prototype.idAttribute I'll accept, because it throws an immediate error.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer but that's not correct in general! the reverse relation must have id of it's own class not parent class! maybe there's problem with your api!

Answer (score 0):

Created a JSFiddle with above code , http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumaranantha/PuLxQ/6/, it doesn't throw any error.

```
var Clip = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    idAttribute: "mediaItemId",
    defaults: {
        node: {} //could be problem here
    }
});
```

I just sense problem could be (not sure) with having an object in defaults map, you should avoid using objects/arrays in defaults, they will get shared across all instances. If you can post response from fetch call, that should help us debug it further.

Comment: I removed it and still throws error when saving the model.
The response to the fetch call is on the screenshot at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @RaviHamsa how you tested with that fiddle? You haven't loaded relational! It just says `TypeError: Backbone.RelationalModel is undefined`

Comment: I didn't use the fiddle to test. I tested on my local setup. The fiddle version can't load my local JSON.